# How to restore a local WordPress site after reinstalling XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp, localhost

as a beginner I think I've done some really dumb mistake and I wanna see if there's something I can do to get myself out of it.

I've had local wordpress site installed on XAMPP server. Some bugs occurred and I decided to reinstall XAMPP. I had copied my entire mysql and htdocs folders for backup and then uninstalled XAMPP. I thought that restoring it would be easy as replacing the folders back, but well... it isn't.
Can't seem to find any way to use these backup folders to restore my site.

Is there any possible way to restore it?

after installing XAMPP again -

1. replacing mysql/data folder with the old one
2. replacing entire mysql folder with the old one
3. inserting my website folder from old htcdocs to new htcdocs: before + after installing wordpress

Comment: What MySQL version? The entire mysql datadir can only be treated as a complete replacements, you can't replace parts of it. What is the error log of MySQL on startup? The htdocs is independent.